# How to perform screen recording with the help of selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to record my script. How can I record it using selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Monte Media Library for this purpose. Download MonteScreenRecorder.jar and add it to your project. Use like this below:

```
         GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment//
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()//
        .getDefaultScreenDevice()//
        .getDefaultConfiguration();





        ScreenRecorder screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc,
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
        CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
        DepthKey, (int)24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
        QualityKey, 1.0f,
        KeyFrameIntervalKey, (int) (15 * 60)),
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey,"black",
        FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
        null);
```

Before starting your actual test begins just start your screen recorder:

```
 screenRecorder.start();
```

and finally stops when test ends.