# Record browser sessions via selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to record / generate a video file of the browser session for selenium webdriver with the following setup?

Environment / Test Setup:

- e2e web tests (written in any language)
- selenium standalone server with chrome

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is no direct support from selenium, you may use third party tool like Monte Media Library. See the link:

[How to perform screen recording with the help of selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840125/how-to-perform-screen-recording-with-the-help-of-selenium/36840430#36840430)

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it. I've seen this and was hoping there were other solutions.